# QGIS raster calculator "not equal"?

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

Is there a syntax for "not equal" in the QGIS Raster Calculator?  If so, what is it?

Comment: As a side note, both `!=` as well as `<>` can be used

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`!=` is used to define 'not equal' in QGIS